# On the sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ of $\Delta ABC$, points $D$, $E$, $F$ are taken in such a way that $\frac{BD}{DC} = \frac{CE}{EA} = $

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

How to find the area ?
[The Diagram and the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIBh3.jpg)

Comment: The diagram isn't attached.

Comment: @SakethMalyala It is attached, click on the number $1$ towards the end of the OP

Comment: I have edited the formatting now.

Comment: I changed your title into a question so if others have the same question as yours, it is much easier to be searched on the Internet....

Answer (score 1):

We can find the area of the required triangle using Feynman's Triangle Problem, also known as the "One-Seventh Area Triangle" problem. A solution for the more-general case is called Routh's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G\in EC$ such that $DG||BE$ and $GC=2x$.

Thus, by Thales $$\frac{EG}{2x}=\frac{BD}{DC}=2,$$ which gives $EG=4x$, $EC=6x$ and $AE=3.$

Thus, by Thales again we obtain:
$$\frac{AP}{PD}=\frac{AE}{EG}=\frac{3x}{4x}=\frac{3}{4}.$$
Now, let $I\in DC$ such that $EI||AD$ and $DI=y$.

Thus, by Thales $IC=2y$ and from here $DC=3y$ and $BD=6y$ and by Thales again we obtain:
$$\frac{BP}{PE}=\frac{BD}{DI}=\frac{6y}{y}=6.$$
Id est, $$AP:PR:RD=BQ:QP:PE=CR:RQ:QF=3:3:1.$$
Hence, $$S_{\Delta PQR}=\frac{1}{2}S_{\Delta QPC}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}S_{\Delta QEC}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{7}S_{\Delta BEC}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{2}{3}S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{7}S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{7}\cdot106.61=15.23.$$